# Stop react async first state change after a second change while loading first change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-state

**Context**: I have a state, `usersData` that gets updated each time the user filters their data. This is a large object that takes time to query the user data and set the new state to be used.

The user initiates a filter change, `change1`, and this takes about 5 seconds to load, immediately, they click on a different filter which initiates a `change2` which takes only 1 second to load.

**Problem**: The `change2` is accurately reflected as the state, but `change1` is still loading and then updates the `usersData` state after a few seconds.

**Intention**: `change2` should be reflected in the `usersData` state and `change1` should have been voided once `change2` was initiated

So not sure how to void loading state change, after another change is loaded.

```
const [usersData, toggleUsersData] = useState({})

function queryAndChange(filter_type) {
  // call api and get new object for users data based off filter_type
  new_state = await fetch(...)
  toggleUsersData(new_state)
}

....
// in a different file, called queryAndChange once and then again right after

queryAndChange(change1)
//0.5seconds later
queryAndChange(change2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set an [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) as a ref whenever you create a new api call. If an `AbortController` was already assigned to the ref, abort it, and then assign a new one:

```
const controller = useRef(null)

function queryAndChange(filter_type) {
  controller.current?.abort()

  const ctrl = new AbortController()
  const controller.current = ctrl

  // call api and get new object for users data based off filter_type
  const newState = await fetch(url, { signal: ctrl.signal, /* other options */ })

  toggleUsersData(newState)
}
```

You can also add a `useEffect` with a cleanup function to abort the call if the component is unmounted:

```
useEffect(() => () => {
  controller.current?.abort()
}, [])
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my case. Thank you. I need to ensure that most of my api calls are aborted in case the request is no longer needed.